# Show nonempty interior implies positive exterior measure.

Tags: real-analysis, outer-measure

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ I claim if the interior is non empty, then it has positive exterior measure. If $E$ has non empty interior, then

$$E \subset\bigcup_{B \subset E \text{open}}B \neq \emptyset$$

As $ B \subset E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, open sets are of the form

$$(a,b) \times ... \times (a,b) \space n \text{copies}$$

and so we at least have

$$m_*(E)= \inf \sum_{i=1}^nm_*((a_i,b_i))=\sum_{i=1}^n \vert b_i-a_i \vert > 0.$$

So long as $a_i \neq b_i$ which is guantateed since we have nonempty interior. Is this good enough? Trying to go based strictly off definition of interior and exterior measure. Basic definitions.

Comment: Not correct. The second equality is not justified.

Comment: are you referring to the equality after $m_*(E)$ or the one after that @geetha290krm

Comment: The one after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer measure is monotone. There exist $a_i<b_i, i=1,2..,n$ such that $(a_1,b_1)\times (a_2,b_2)\times....\times (a_n,b_n) \subseteq E$ so $m_{*}(E) \geq m_{*} ((a_1,b_1)\times (a_2,b_2)\times....\times (a_n,b_n))=\prod (b_i-a_i) >0$.

Comment: where exactly do you use that your have nonempty interior?

Comment: that the union of all open sets contained in $E$ is nonempty.

Comment: is it the step where u say there exists an interval

Comment: Yes, any set with non-empty interior contains an open rectangle.  @HossienSahebjame

Comment: and for a counterexample to the converse does the fat cantor set work

Comment: and for the last one don't you mean $\Pi \vert b_i-a_i \vert$?

Comment: $a_i<b_i$ so $|b_i-a_i|=b_i-a_i$